# Do multiple software-threads on a single hardware-thread system execute sequentially?

Tags: multithreading, hardware, computer-architecture

I understand that if a system consists of multiple hardware-threads the scheduler
assigns software-threads to hardware-threads.

However, hypothetically, let's imagine a system that does only consist of a single-hardware-thread. Is the execution of multiple software-threads forbidden or does the program execute sequentially?

Comment: Pre-emptive multi-tasking was common long before hardware multi-processing was common. E.g. Windows 95 introduced such a scheduler, and it was the standard approach in Unix since forever. A pre-emptive scheduler occasionally suspends the running task and lets another thread execute for the next timeslice. This just requires a hardware timer or interrupt that causes the scheduler to run when the timeslice is over.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_(computing)#Time_slice

Comment: A system does not consist of hardware or software threads, that whole statement is misleading. An (operating) system may *provide* multiple threads to a process, and there is usually hardware support like interrupts used, even if the CPU has only a single core. So please clarify what you mean by "single hardware-threads" - only single core CPUs? Or a CPU with no interrupts? Or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is far from hypothetical:

- Before multithreading CPUs, running multiple [threads](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)) and processes on a single threaded CPU was a common practice, supported by many OSes.
- There a still a lot of microcontrollers around that work with a single single threaded core. So it’s still a relevant question.

The way multiple threads are run on a single CPU execution thread depends a lot on the OS / execution environment / library that you are using and the underlying threading principle:

- preemptive multithreading is done in a similar way than multiprocessing, but it is much lighter and faster: the execution of threads is performed in small slices that are each executed sequentially. The fact that there is a frequent [switch](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch) creates the illusion of concurrency at the cost of performance.
- cooperative multithreading let each thread decide when the switch to another thread is to be done. In the worst case, two threads may just be executed one after the other in a sequential way.  The impression of concurrency is less convincing, but performance is be better (less switching overhead).
- usually I/O operations are associated with some kind of waiting.  I/O calls therefore often lead - in both models - to a potential thread switch. Since the I/O waiting time is an order of magnitude longer (milliseconds) than thread switching (nanoseconds), this kind of switch has little impact on perceived performance but significantly increases system throughput in I/O intensive applications.

More information:

- [This article about realtime scheduling](https://www.embedded.com/comparing-real-time-scheduling-on-the-linux-kernel-and-an-rtos/) provides some more explanation and has some nice figures about how threads are scheduled for sequential execution (including how priorities can be managed).
- Introduction about preemptive threading [in Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/about-processes-and-threads) .
- [C++ standard library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) is available on all C++implementations starting from c++11. Note the function that provides a [hint about hardware threading limits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55909228/3723423). It is not guaranteed to provide meaningful info but does on MSVC if you’re looking for some [experimentation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35525942/3723423).

Answer (score 1):

First consider that if a single core system allowed only one thread, then it would be logical that a processor with 16 cores would allow only sixteen threads - my Mac runs a few hundred right now.

What happens is that you can have as many threads as you want (within reason). Typically each core starts running one thread, and either when the thread needs to wait for something or enough time has passed, the thread will be paused and another starts running.

Comment: To slightly extend this to what OP presumably wants to know: it's the machine's (not the application's) prerogative to decide which thread to run at which time on which core. So the machine _might_ interleave your two threads on its single core, or it could choose to do one after the other.

Comment: Worth mention that threads can be set with different levels of priority. No need to wait for a thread to stop, threads with higher priority will be scheduled first, what could break any "feeling" of sequentiality

Comment: @Flater Actually it is the operating system's prerogative. (Those are not the same thing)

Comment: @user253751: From the perspective we're discussing, "machine" is sufficiently descriptive (and commonly used). You're taking it too literal. It's not referring to actual physical hardware, it's referring to _whatever environment_ on which this application will run. Whether that's an actual physical hardware device, which OS it is, whether it's a VM, ... is irrelevant for this topic.

Answer (score 0):

Let me now try to explain:

So far as I am aware *(and I've been around these parts a* ***long*** *time),* there is no such thing as a "hardware," nor a "software," *thread.*  "Threading" is a purely-software concept – agnostic to whatever-is the underlying hardware that runs it.

The **software** concept is that "the computer's workload" consists of one-or-more independent "processes," each of which owns such resources as memory-segments and file-handles.  Then, *within* each process, we have one-or-more independent "threads," all of which share the owning process's resources.

The **hardware** concept, then, is that: "the operating system must now find a way to run it, on whatever hardware it finds that it has."  If there is only one CPU/core, then quite-necessarily only one *[thread of one ...]* process can execute at a time; otherwise they will indeed be "physically simultaneous."

The **programmer** concept therefore must be that: *"it is entirely unpredictable."*  You must never write software that is dependent upon an operating-system's decisions: "indeed, exactly the opposite."